# Convert two hexadecimal strings into datetime object

Tags: matlab, hex

I have a hex number (`uint32`) stored as a character string. The character string is `'DA5CE697'`. I want to convert this to a normal hex number on which I can perform some hex arithmetic operations. Are there any functions that can do this in matlab (like `str2num` for normal numbers)? Or if there is any other way of going about it?

**Update**

The character string provided above is the first part of an NTP timestamp. I am using:

```
datetime(t1 + 1/t2, 'ConvertFrom', 'epochtime', 'epoch', '1900-01-01')
```

To get the exact time from a data file. Both `t1` and `t2` are 4 bytes. The values for them are:

```
t1 = 'DA5CE697';
t2 = '7F14FCE7';
```

Ideally, I could have gone about reading 4 bytes at once and get the values for `t1` and `t2`. But I have to traverse the file 1 byte at a time (some constraints). So, I am stitching back the values for `t1` and `t2` (to avoid missing zeros. Otherwise, it stores '05' as '5').

Comment: please show your previous effort...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your string *is* a hexadecimal representation of your `uint32` number. If you instead want the integer (decimal) version of your hexadecimal string, you will need to convert it using [`hex2dec`](http://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/hex2dec.html) to be able to perform arithmetic within MATLAB.

```
f = hex2dec('DA5CE697')
%// 3663521431
```

Alternately, if you want your hexadecimal value to be cast as a floating point number you can instead use [`hex2num`](http://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/hex2num.html).

MATLAB does not have a hexadecimal datatype so I'm not sure what "hexadecimal arithmetic" you're expecting to be able to perform.

**Update**

Now that you have provided more information, you will combine `t1` and `t2` into a time stamp using `hex2dec` on both of them (as I showed above) and then perform the arithmetic using the decimal values.

```
t1 = 'DA5CE697';
t2 = '7F14FCE7';

datetime(hex2dec(t1) + 1/hex2dec(t2), 'ConvertFrom', 'epochtime', 'epoch', '1900-01-01')
%// 03-Feb-2016 20:50:31
```

Comment: Thanks for the response but I do not want to change it into a decimal number.

The hex string is stored as char. I just want that character string in hexadecimal numbers as I cannot perform hex arithmetic on character strings.

Comment: @AbhinavPrakash MATLAB does not have a hexadecimal datatype

Comment: okay. so no direct functions for conversion then. Any idea how to go about this problem then?

Comment: @AbhinavPrakash You haven't actually explained what you're trying to do. Also, I added a section at the end of my answer that may help you out?

Comment: Well, the character string provided above is the first part of an NTP timestamp. I am using:

"datetime(t1 + 1/t2, 'ConvertFrom', 'epochtime', 'epoch', '1900-01-01')"

to get the exact time from a data file. Both t1 and t2 are 4 bytes. The values for them are:

t1 = DA5CE697
t2 = 7F14FCE7

Ideally, I could have gone about reading 4 bytes at once and get the values for t1 and t2. But I have to traverse the file 1 byte at a time(some constraints). So, i am stitching back the values for t1 and t2(to avoid missing zeros. Otherwise, it stores '05' as '5').

Comment: I am trying the method you have provided above. Will update the post more clearly in case I still do not get the desired result. Sorry for the sloppy explanation! New here.

And thanks for the response.

Comment: @AbhinavPrakash I updated my post with the answer for your specific case.

Comment: OMG it worked! Can I buy you beer!

Thank you so much :)